# Remove border from charts if charts is present on excel sheet using xlsxwriter or openpyxl in python

Tags: python, charts, border, xlsxwriter

I am trying to remove border from charts which is present on my excel sheet so how can i remove using xlsxwriter library or openpyxl library can anyone help?

I have gone through Xlsxwriter documentation and openpyxl documentation but in both libraries i can see they have given us functions to create charts(graph) but i am not able to get what if graph is already present in excel file and if we want to change the formatting or style of charts then what should we do.

Comment: Remove the border edge around the chart area? For xlsxwriter Use **<chart>.set_chartarea({'border': {'none': True}})**

Comment: There is no method for openpyxl. Potentially it could be achieved but you would need to do some deep dive into openpyxl.